How To Convert Postgresql Timestamp With Time Zone To UTC In Javascript
I have my postgres table returning a whole bunch of date values client-side formatted like so:
2024-05-14 15:11:38.208073+00
Obviously, +00 indicates this is (properly) stored in UTC format.
From here, all I need to do is convert this timestamp into a workable date object in Javacript, so I can add/subtract time to it as I see fit.
Currently I am trying this:
        const date = new Date(item.time);
        const formattedDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        const hour = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':00'; // Formatting hour to display as 00:00
        const dayOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][date.getDay()];
        const monthName = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });

Technically, this all works. However the ISSUE is that new Date(item.time) is automatically converting the timestamp into EST (my local timezone) rather than keeping it in UTC format.
This SEEMS like it should be simple to do, however I've been researching for a clearcut solution for over an hour now with no success (everything out there seems like a hack).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT 1:
I can see that, in fact, new Date(item.time) IS converting the UTC timestamp passed in to my local time. Tested like so:
 console.log("TIME BEFORE: " , item.time)
 const date = new Date(item.time);
 console.log("TIME AFTER: ", date)

Logs out:
TIME BEFORE:  2024-05-14T13:27:24.357094+00:00
TIME AFTER:  Tue May 14 2024 09:27:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Test like this:
(()=>{
const startDate = "2024-05-14 15:11:38.208073+00"
console.log("TIME BEFORE: " , startDate)
const date = new Date(startDate);
console.log("TIME AFTER: ", date)
})();



JavaScript date/time values are always UTC internally. Creating the Date instance is not converting your timestamp. Also, it's not clear why you'd immediately turn the date back into a string instead of using the native Date APIs to extract the "pieces" of the value.

Looking at your code more closely, you're calling .getHours() instead of .getUTCHours(), and etc. I don't know where you've spent time searching, but MDN has fairly complete documentation of Date instances.

@Pointy edited above to show that new Date() is in fact converting the input timestamp with time zone (UTC) to my local timezone (EST)

No, it is not.  What's "converting" the date is the process of going back to a string. You paid no attention to my recommendation to look into the getUTC APIs.

@Pointy I have modified the other aspects of my code to reflect your recommendation, however you are incorrect in saying new Date() does not convert a postgresql timestamp with time zone to a date object in your machines local time. Check the second update and code example for you to try in Chrome yourself.

OK. Live long and prosper.

@Pointy maybe there's a disconnect in the language I'm using. In my most recent edit, I am curious to know why when I log the result of new Date("2024-05-14 15:11:38.208073+00") (which should be May 14th, 2024 at 3:11:38 PM UTC) it logs May 14th, 2024 @ 11:11:38 EST. Forget about any other methods used within the code as this is done basically immediately. It should produce a date object, but it should not modify the time

The timestamp being passing to the built–in parser is not supported by ECMA-262 (it has a space between the date and time components instead of the letter "T" and has too many digits in the decimal seconds part) so parsing is implementation dependent.
If correctly parsed (and that is not guaranteed, see above), it will be converted to a millisecond offset from the ECMAScript epoch, which is 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z (i.e. midnight at the start of 1 Jan 1970 UTC). ECMA-262 calls that value a time value. It represents a single moment in time and is the only data value held by a Date instance.
Various toString methods of Date instances produce timestamps based on the time value that all represent the same instant in time, but may have different values for the displayed date and time depending on the offset used. In the OP, the following timestamps:

2024-05-14T13:27:24.357094+00:00
Tue May 14 2024 09:27:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

represent exactly the same moment in time (except for the missing decimal seconds in the second timestamp). The difference in the displayed times is a consequence of the different offsets used for the timestamps. It's not because the Date instance itself has an associated offset or timezone.
E.g.


let d = new Date('2024-05-14T15:11:38.208+00');

// Return a timestamp the same as the initial string
console.log(d.toISOString());
// Return a timestamp for the system's current regional settings
console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-ca'));
// Return a timestamp for Auckland, New Zealand
console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-ca',{
  timeZone:'Pacific/Auckland',
  timeZoneName:'short'
}));



PS UTC is a time standard, not a format. ;-)

That's interesting because the string returned is how postgresql stores it as a timestamp with timezone. Researching to see if there is a more appropriate column value type to use that includes T/more compatible formatting

@Ethan— +00 isn't a timezone, it's an offset. In this case it's +0 (i.e. zero hours from UTC) so equivalent to GMT, Irish Winter Time, Azores Summer Time, East Greenland Summer Time, and so on.
